# How to express 1+3+5+7+9 in sum notation

Tags: math-operators

I want to use `\sum` to express

```
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 ... + 2n - 1.
```

Can I? Or what methods can I use to express this sequence?

Comment: in math mode `\sum_{i=1}^{n}2i-1`

Comment: @touhami - Don't forget to place parentheses around `2i-1`. :-)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Just to clarify: Are you asking how to use TeX to typeset the sum using summation notation, or are you asking how to use TeX to perform the summation itself?

Comment: @Mico: The sum is `n^2` ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are four ways to write the sum in question. It may be written with a small or large summation symbol, and with the limits of summation typeset either to the side of or below/above the summation symbol.

The version shown in the upper-left cell of the following screenshot is what's commonly used for inline-math notation, while the version shown in the lower-right cell is what's generally used for displaystyle-math notation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cc}
\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) & 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (2i-1)\\[3ex]
\displaystyle\sum\nolimits_{i=1}^n (2i-1)&  
\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (2i-1) \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```